# Why can't I set hyperref's pdfinfo from within a group? (Is it a bug?)

Tags: hyperref, pdf, grouping

When I run the following code (using `hyperref` version `2012/09/27 v6.83g`), I do not get any errors or warnings, but the metadata I set using `pdfinfo` doesn't appear. If I uncomment the `\@firstofone` line, effectively removing the group, it does.

I could not see any documentation in the manual that states one must be careful to use `pdfinfo` outside of all groups, so I have a feeling this might be a bug. Due to the grouping issue, I suspect this bug is caused by internal assignments in `hyperref` being local instead of global. I get a bit lost when reading the `hyperref` code, so I have so far been unable to determine the cause (and therefore a solution) to this problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
%\@firstofone
{
    \hypersetup{pdfinfo={extrainfo={yes please}}}
}

\begin{document}
    Check the pdf metadata.
\end{document}
```

(Of course, in my actual example, I don't know how many levels deep I need to 'escape', and neither do I know any such way to escape! I cannot easily test my assumption about assignment locality as I am not aware of any trick to set a flag or something to make all assignments in a group global even if they were not defined `\global`, and I expect that may have other unwanted consequences anyway.)

Is anyone able to offer a fix or a workaround?

Comment: Oh, and I'm using the `pdflatex` workflow.

Comment: If I use `Author` instead of `extrainfo`, the setting is respected independently of grouping. The "unknown" key instead is added only if at the outer level.

Comment: Please send bug reports direct to the package author. A question and answer site isn't really the right place for bug reports.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed in hyperref 2012/10/11 v6.83h.

Comment: Confirmed. Thank you very much! (While I roughly understand the fix, I'm sorry I couldn't have been of more help in identifying the issue.)